# Предзагрузка audio в javascript

Tags: javascript, аудио

Как реализовать загрузку звуков и мелодий в javascript? Интересует именно полная загрузка файла с последующей возможностью его проигрыша.

Comment: вопрос решен тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313646/how-to-preload-a-sound-in-javascript

Comment: @Jean-Claude Стесняюсь спросить, и какой из 6-ти ответов Вы считаете ответом на мой вопрос?

Comment: А что вы пробовали? И обычно загрузка файлов это больше проблема бэкЭнда чем фронтЭнда.

Comment: @Vartlok ну конечно же я ничего не пробовал. Просто так вот шел мимо и дай, думаю, задам вопрос, потролю знатоков... Хотите ответить? Отвечайте. А непродуктивные комментарии - в топку. Можете ответить причем здесь к вопросу хоть близко Ваш комментарий о проблеме бэкэнда? Я вопрос про бэкэнд задал? Или Вы мне сейчас будете рассказывать, что бэкэнд может чего-то не отдать? Так я не веду речь о плохом соединении. Меня интересует сама возоможность загрузки звукового файла полностью. Почувствуйте (прочувствуйте) разницу.

Comment: @Softinaria, вы вроде бы не первый день на StackOverflow. В вопросе не видна ваша проблема, и сейчас на него можно ответить "по-разному".  Лучше добавьте деталей, поясните, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: @Nofate Так ответьте хоть как-нибудь? Каких деталей Вы хотите для вопроса, "как загрузить полностью файл и использовать потом"? При этом этот файл - аудио. При этом это javascript. Что непонятного? Вот скажите, что именно Вам непонятно в вопросе? Какие могут быть разночтения? Вроде не первый день на StackOverflow, а появляетесь для разведения холивара.